# Navegação de site sem reload usando ajax não funciona corretamente

Tags: jquery, ajax

tudo certo?

Seguinte, estou fazendo um site com navegação em `AJAX`, para que não seja necessário carregar o site toda vez que for acessar uma página. Home, notícias, contato, etc..

Consegui fazer o site, atualiza a url, botão de voltar, tudo certinho.. 
Porém estou com o seguinte problema

---

**Compartilhar/Refresh:** 
Quando eu faço o refresh da página ou tento compartilhar o link com outra pessoa, ele não carrega o site corretamente. Está abrindo apenas a seção daquela página específica. Ex.: Se eu quero compartilhar o link `site.com.br/sobre.php` ele abre somente o texto daquela página. O header, menu, rodapé não aparecem. O `css` também vem desconfigurado.

Se for no primeiro load do site, não tem problema algum.. Mas se der refresh ou compartilhar o link com amigo, esse problema já acontece.

Obs.: Quero manter esse tipo de navegação pela velocidade que consegui obter no site.

---

Este é o código que estou utilizando:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var content = $('#site'),
        firstLink = $(".navbar li:first-child a").attr("href"),
        navLink = $(".navbar li a");

    content.load(firstLink);

    navLink.on("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var newLink = $(this).attr("href");

         History.pushState(null, null, newLink);

        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        content.load(newLink, function () {
            FB.XFBML.parse();
        });
    });

    History.Adapter.bind(window, "statechange", function() {
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $("a[href='" + History.getState().title + "']").addClass("active");
        content.load(document.location.href); 
    });
});
```

E este é o meu menu:

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="/content/home.php">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="/content/servicos.php">Serviços</a></li>
            <li><a href="/content/advogados.php">Advogados</a></li>
            <li><a href="/content/escritorio.php">Escritório</a></li>
            <li><a href="/content/noticias.php">Notícias</a></li>
            <li><a href="/content/contato.php">Contato</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Acho que seria isso.
Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeceria muito!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu script PHP para as partes internas do site retorna somente a parte do meio do site. Então quando você faz uma requisição XHR(AJAX), você recebe o que quer, somente a parte do meio e você joga o que recebeu dentro do template que veio com a home, no entanto ao acessar diretamente a URL, você não tem os dados que você recebe acessando a home do site (o seu template).

Então quando você acessa diretamente a url dele, ele vai retornar só a parte do meio.

Você tem dois meios de resolver isso:

1 - No seu script php você pode verificar nos headers se a requisição sendo feita é XHR.
Exemplo:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest') {
  //retorna só o meio da pagina
}
else {
  //da um jeito de montar a página inteira com cabeçalho, rodapé, etc.
}
```

2 - *Renderizar* a página em javascript.

A maioria dos sites que utilizam esse tipo de navegação, são chamadas de "single page apps", traduzindo: "Aplicação com uma página só" pois utilizam o servidor apenas para mandar a página inicial e fazem a maior parte do trabalho no cliente(javascript).

Existem diversos frameworks e bibliotecas que visam resolver esse problema, entre eles:

Projeto do Facebook:
https://facebook.github.io/react/

Projeto do Google:
https://angularjs.org/

Duas opções que considero um pouco mais simples:

http://emberjs.com/

http://backbonejs.org/

Projeto do Google que esta em beta ainda, mas se o seu objetivo é aprendizado, eu recomendo:
https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/

Você também pode tentar criar sua própria solução. Que basicamente teria de verificar se a url é a da home e caso contrário montar o template. Os frameworks supracitados fazem muito mais que isso e são bem diferentes um do outro.

Eu acho válido aprender a utilizar qualquer um deles, pois ao aprender um vai ser mais fácil aprender outro caso necessário.

Comment: @Eirk Já havia lido um pouco a respeito sobre o angular.js, os demais eu não conhecia. Pretendo trabalhar mais com essa teconologia pois ela, diferentemente do php - ao menos pelo que conheço, da muito mais agilidade, dinâmica e velocidade para a página. Angular me parece a opção mais 'conhecida', porém não encontrei um bom guia para iniciantes. Você teria algum para recomendar? Com mais tempo vou olhar as demais referências que você passou. Obrigado por enquanto.

Comment: @celsomtrindade Todos esses frameworks são relativamente novos então a frequência de mudanças é grande, devido à isso é bem difícil encontrar conteúdo de qualidade em português. Eu recomendo procurar no google com filtro de data pro ultimo ano só. Vou editar minha resposta pra adicionar mais algumas alternativas.